# Build this formula in LaTeX

Tags: math-operators

I'm working on my term paper and have to include the calculation for the Google PageRank.

This is what it looks like in Wikipedia:

[image]

How can this be represented in LaTeX? I'm especially struggling with the definition below the sum.

Comment: A handy tip: the Wikipedia math syntax is very similar to LaTeX. If you simply go to that Wikipedia page and hit 'Edit', you will see that the code for that formula is `PR(p_i) = \frac{1-d}{N} + d \sum_{p_j \in M(p_i)} \frac{PR (p_j)}{L(p_j)}`, which in this case you can just paste into a LaTeX document.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: @Nathaniel It is even easier than that.  Just select the formula with your mouse as you would select text.  Then hit Ctrl+C and you will have the formula code in the clipboard.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should be a part of basic knowledge about LaTeX ... For example:

```
\[
PR_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \sum_{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}}} \frac{PR_i}{c_j}
\]
```

I strongly encourage you to read *No so short introduction to Latex ...*. it can be easy find by googling internet :-).

**Addendum:**
Considering comments of @Bernard and @egreg, the above -- basic -- math can be improved with more advanced math seting:

- use of `mathtools` package and his macro `\smashoperator`, which reduce space between `\sum` operator and neighborhood variable
- change the notation of summation range to `1\leq j\leg n` or to `\sum_{j=1}^n`
- use `\mathit{PR}` since it seems that PR is single variable

All those variation are collected in code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
PR_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \smashoperator{\sum_{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}}} \frac{PR_i}{c_j}
\]

\[
\mathit{PR}_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \sum_{1\leq j\leq n} \frac{\mathit{PR}_i}{c_j}
\]

\[
\mathit{PR}_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \sum_{1=j}^{n} \frac{\mathit{PR}_i}{c_j}
\]

\[
\mathit{PR}_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}} \frac{\mathit{PR}_i}{c_j}
\]
\end{document}
```

Picture of all variants are below:

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
For advance math settings exist AMS math bundle (`amsmath`, `amssymb`, ...) and many others. Among them let me emphasize `mathools` which is already used in the first addendum. Those packages provide many advanced math environments and macros. Among later are different dots ellipsis adopted to particular use. For example `\dotsc` as pointed @larked in his comment. Its use in this case is:

```
\[
\mathit{PR}_i = \frac{1-d}{n} + d \sum_{j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}} \frac{PR_i}{c_j}
\]
```

which gives:

[image]

*Note:* For addendum goes credits to autor of comments which share their reach knowledge about LaTeX and math typesetting with it.

*Edit:* corrected are small type and spelling errors as pointed  CarLaTeX in his comment.

Comment: Maybe it would look still nicer with `\smashoperator`?

Comment: @Bernard, you have right, however, this is already 'advanced' math :-). I will ad this option latter.

Comment: It was only a suggestion – only based on my personal taste. For sure, it may look advanced to beginners…

Comment: Possibly better `\mathit{PR}`, because it is to be considered a single variable name. Also `1\leq j\leq n` makes the subscript shorter.

Comment: I like the third formula the best, not in small part because it's the most compact.

Comment: I also perfer `\dotsc` for 'dots with commas'. There's also `\dotsb` for 'dots for binary relations' etc. See also here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Dots

Comment: Me too .. , but as I already mentioned, this is over basic mathematics, what was my intention to show OP. I will incorporate your comment to the answer (soon).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you for pointing typing errors. Now corrected.

Answer (score 16):

Notice that you can find the Wikipedia's LaTeX code directly from the Wikipedia page.

From the German [Page Rank](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) page (the English page has a slightly different formula), first select the required formula and then press Ctrl+C. You can then paste the code directly, as I've done here:

```
PR_{i}={\frac  {1-d}{n}}+d\,\sum _{{j\in \{1,\dots ,n\}}}{\frac  {PR_{j}}{c_{j}}}
```

Sometimes, you might need to polish it a bit, but at least you have a starting point. Apart from specific style choices, take into account that, according to [this help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula), MediaWiki uses a subset of the AMS-LaTeX markup. By using the full capabilities of packages like `mathtools`, you can of course produce better formatted equations, as [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316975/50910) clearly shows.